# .net core EF Memory Leak

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I try to call a method inside my query but i got an error like

**The client projection contains a reference to a constant expression of 'Project.WebApi.Controllers.OfferController' through the instance method 'Hesapla'. This could potentially cause a memory leak; consider making the method static so that it does not capture constant in the instance.**

What am i doing wrong ?

```
Demands = s.Demands.Where(w => Array.IndexOf(rolesArray, "53") > -1 ? w.ApproveRoadmap == 22 || w.ApproveRoadmap == 25 : true)
                .Select(d => new
                {
                    DemandId = d.Id,
                    DemandCode = d.Code,
                    StockId = d.StockCategoryId,
                    StockCode = d.StockCategory.Code,
                    StockName = d.StockCategory.Name,
                    StockAmount = d.StockAmount,
                    ProductFeatureUnit = d.ProductFeatureUnit.Name,
                    Description = d.Description,
                    ApproveRoadmap = d.ApproveRoadmap,
                    Link = d.Link,
                    Category = d.Category,
                    AcceptedOfferSum = Hesapla(d.Id),
                    Notes = s.DemandGroupRoadmapNotes.Where(w => w.DemandId == d.Id).Select(note => new
                    {
                        Id = note.Id,
                        WritedPersonalName = note.WritedPersonal.NameSurname,
                        Description = note.Description,
                        ProcessNote = note.ProcessNote,
                        CustomDescription = note.CustomDescription,
                        DemandGroupId = note.DemandGroupId,
                        ProcessDate = note.ProcessDate
                    }).ToList(),
                    Offers = d.OfferItems.Select(o => new
                    {
                        CompanyName = o.Offer.Company.Name,
                        OfferId = o.Offer.Id,
                        OfferItemId = o.Id,
                        OfferCreatedPersonnel = o.Offer.CreatedPersonnel.NameSurname,
                        CompanyId = o.Offer.CompanyId,
                        OfferName = o.Offer.Name,
                        PaymentMethod = o.Offer.PaymentMethod,
                        CheckDay = o.Offer.CheckDay,
                        KdvIncluded = o.Offer.KdvIncluded,
                        KdvRate = o.Offer.KdvRate,
                        OfferReceivedDate = o.Offer.OfferReceivedDate,
                        Currency = o.Currency,
                        CashUnitPrice = o.CashUnitPrice,
                        DayMaturity1 = o.DayMaturity1,
                        DayMaturity2 = o.DayMaturity2,
                        DeadlineDay = o.DeadlineDay,
                        Note = o.Note,
                        CurrencyValue = _db.CurrencyByDates.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(w => w.Date == o.Offer.OfferReceivedDate && w.Symbol == o.Currency).Value,
                        ApprovalStatus = o.OfferItemApproval,
                        TestApprovalStatus = o.OfferItemTestRequired,
                        OfferFiles = o.OfferFiles.ToList()
                    }).ToList()
                }).ToList()
```

the method i call

```
public double Hesapla(int Id)
    {
        return db.OfferItems.AsTracking().Where(w => w.OfferItemApproval.DemandId == Id && w.OfferItemApproval.Status == 1)
            .Select(se => se.Offer.KdvIncluded == 1 ? se.Offer.PaymentMethod == 1 || se.Offer.PaymentMethod == 4
                ? se.Currency == "₺"
                    ? ((Convert.ToDouble((se.CashUnitPrice * Convert.ToDecimal(se.Demand.StockAmount)))) *
                       Convert.ToDouble(db.CurrencyByDates.FirstOrDefault(f =>
                               f.Date == se.Offer.OfferReceivedDate && f.Symbol == se.Currency)
                           .Value))
                    : se.Currency != "₺"
                        ? (Convert.ToDouble((se.CashUnitPrice * Convert.ToDecimal(se.Demand.StockAmount))) *
                           Convert.ToDouble(db.CurrencyByDates.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(w =>
                               w.Date == se.Offer.OfferReceivedDate && w.Symbol == se.Currency).Value))
                        : 0
                : se.Offer.PaymentMethod == 2 || se.Offer.PaymentMethod == 3
                    ? se.Currency == "₺"
                        ? (Convert.ToDouble((se.DayMaturity1 * Convert.ToDecimal(se.Demand.StockAmount))) *
                           Convert.ToDouble(db.CurrencyByDates.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(w =>
                               w.Date == se.Offer.OfferReceivedDate && w.Symbol == se.Currency).Value))
                        : se.Currency != "₺"
                            ? (Convert.ToDouble((se.DayMaturity1 * Convert.ToDecimal(se.Demand.StockAmount))) *
                               Convert.ToDouble(db.CurrencyByDates.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(w =>
                                   w.Date == se.Offer.OfferReceivedDate && w.Symbol == se.Currency).Value))
                            : 0
                    : 0
            : se.Offer.KdvIncluded == 2 ? se.Offer.PaymentMethod == 1 || se.Offer.PaymentMethod == 4
                ? se.Currency == "₺"
                    ? (Convert.ToDouble((se.CashUnitPrice * Convert.ToDecimal(se.Demand.StockAmount))) *
                       KdvRateCalc3(Convert.ToInt32(se.Offer.KdvRate)))
                    : se.Currency != "₺"
                        ? (Convert.ToDouble((se.CashUnitPrice * Convert.ToDecimal(se.Demand.StockAmount))) *
                           KdvRateCalc3(Convert.ToInt32(se.Offer.KdvRate)) * Convert.ToDouble(db.CurrencyByDates
                               .AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(w =>
                                   w.Date == se.Offer.OfferReceivedDate && w.Symbol == se.Currency).Value))
                        : 0
                : se.Offer.PaymentMethod == 2 || se.Offer.PaymentMethod == 3
                    ? se.Currency == "₺"
                        ? (Convert.ToDouble((se.DayMaturity1 * Convert.ToDecimal(se.Demand.StockAmount))) *
                           KdvRateCalc3(Convert.ToInt32(se.Offer.KdvRate)))
                        : se.Currency != "₺"
                            ? (Convert.ToDouble((se.DayMaturity1 * Convert.ToDecimal(se.Demand.StockAmount))) *
                               KdvRateCalc3(Convert.ToInt32(se.Offer.KdvRate)) *
                               Convert.ToDouble(db.CurrencyByDates.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(w =>
                                   w.Date == se.Offer.OfferReceivedDate && w.Symbol == se.Currency).Value))
                            : 0
                    : 0
            : 0).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: Try making the `Hesapla` method `static`, and passing the `DbContext` instance as a parameter.

Comment: @RichardDeeming I sent dbcontext as parameter but it didn't work. I've tried to creat a new DbContext instance in the method and it worked that way.

Comment: @RichardDeeming this happened and I changed the method (something like `Hesapla` here) to a static method and it worked. Why did it work? Can you kindly explain this to me? Thanks